# Lorentz boost matrix

Tags: special-relativity, tensor-calculus, inertial-frames

In my textbook, there is a proof that the dot product of 2 four-vectors is invariant under a Lorentz transformation. While I understood most of the derivation (I am a beginner and we haven't done any math regarding this notation), there is one step which I do not understand:

$$ (\Lambda^μ_α)(\Lambda_{μβ})x^αy^β =(\Lambda^μ_α)(\Lambda^β_μ)x^αy_β.$$

As you can see the $\beta$ subscript on the $\Lambda$ becomes a superscript, while the $\beta$ superscript on $y$ vector becomes a subscript.
I know for a fact that you can change the index position on the $\Lambda$ but the index also changes, meaning we use a new character when the index goes up or down after we multiply $\Lambda$ with the metric tensor.
So how does the book do it here?

Comment: You can raise and lower indices with the Minkowski metric.

Comment: yes but you also have to change the index greek letter when you do that. Meaning if you change a superscript to a subscript you also have to change the letter  i.e from beta to sigma.

Comment: They are dummy indices as you sum over them. I.e you can call them whatever you want to. Hence  $u^\mu v_\mu = u_\sigma v^\sigma $.

Comment: honestly i do not understand it.Once that β goes up it changes lets say to a σ. So the RHS of the equation is the same as above but with the difference that the β superscript on the 2nd Λ is a σ. And you say i can simply just change it to β ? What about the β on the y vector. that also goes down but it stays as β.

Comment: It is true that $x^\mu y_\mu=x_\mu y^\mu$. In the summation convention, repeated indices are summed over implicitly (i.e. we remove the summation symbol and simply define a repeated index, one up one down, to mean that index is summed over), you cannot arbitrarily raise and lower indices *unless* they are summed over, in which case you can move one up *as long as you move the other down*. Indices that are repeated are called "dummy indices", indices that are not repeated at called "free indices".

Answer (score 3):

If you have a quantity with a down index, say $A_\mu$, you can raise the index using the metric (in this case the Minkowski metric $\eta$) as $A_\mu=A^\nu\eta_{\nu\mu}$. In an analogous way, we can lower the index of $B^\mu$ as $B^\mu=B_\nu\eta^{\nu\mu}$.

Now suppose we have a term as in your example where there is a quantity with a down-index next to one with an up-index, and they are contracted (i.e. summed over / named the same) as in $A_\mu B^\mu$. We can raise the index of $A_\mu$ and lower the one of $B^\mu$. It's always good to introduce a new letter when raising or lowering an index if you are not sure. So we would do $A_\mu=A^\nu\eta_{\nu\mu}$ just as before, and $B^\mu=B_\sigma\eta^{\sigma\mu}$ (where I have introduced a new letter $\sigma$ instead of $\nu$). With this we have

\begin{align}
A_\mu B^\mu&=A^\nu\eta_{\nu\mu}B_\sigma\eta^{\sigma\mu}\\
&=A^\nu B_\sigma\eta_{\nu\mu}\eta^{\sigma\mu}.
\end{align}

If we think of the metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ as a matrix, notice that the product $\eta_{\nu\mu}\eta^{\sigma\mu}$ is the way to write the matrix multiplication of a matrix times its inverse in the Einstein convention. A matrix times its inverse gives the identity matrix, whose components are given by a Kronecker delta $\delta_\nu^\sigma$. So if we write $\eta_{\nu\mu}\eta^{\sigma\mu}=\delta_\nu^\sigma$, we are left with

$$A_\mu B^\mu=A^\nu B_\sigma\delta_\nu^\sigma.$$

This last expression is summed over $\nu$ and over $\sigma$, but only the terms with $\sigma=\nu$ survive the sum because of the Kronecker delta: $A^\nu B_\sigma\delta_\nu^\sigma=A^\nu B_\nu$. Renaming now the index $\nu$ as $\mu$ (we can do that, it's a dummy index) we end up with

$$A_\mu B^\mu=A^\mu B_\mu.$$

So with a little more practice you'll be able to identify the change $A_\mu B^\mu\to A^\mu B_\mu$ as something trivial.

Comment: Thanks, now i get it. I was trying something similar,but because this is like day 2 of having to deal with this type of notation + no mathematical background, it was hard to understand! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If I understand OP's question correctly, he does not understand why $\sum_\beta \Lambda_{\mu\beta} y^\beta = \sum_\beta\Lambda_{\mu}^{\;\;\beta} y_\beta$. This is how it works in detail
$$
\sum_\beta \Lambda_{\mu\beta} y^\beta  =\sum_{\beta,\sigma} \Lambda_\mu^{\;\;\sigma} \eta_{\sigma\beta} y^\beta = 
 \sum_\sigma \Lambda_\mu^{\;\;\sigma} y_\sigma = \sum_\beta \Lambda_\mu^{\;\;\beta} y_\beta  $$
I have written out the sum symbol explicitly, but in these expression repeated indices are understood to be summed over.

Note also that I write $\Lambda_\mu^{\;\;\sigma}$ and not $\Lambda_\mu^{\sigma}$ as it is important to know which of the two indices is raised.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i get it. So you can change the index once you see that they sum up?

Comment: Pls accept the answer if you can. Thanks.